# iPhone App baseSDK and iOS deployment target

Tags: iphone

I am in the process of deploying my app to the app store. I am not sure what to set for baseSDK and iOS deployment target. I have the latest iOS 4.1 installed. How can I make sure that it runs on all the devices. My application was build on 4.0.1 (I think).

My iPod has iOS 4.1 (latest) and my iPhone has 4.0. To make my application work on the iPhone I have to lower the baseSDK and iOS deployment target to 3.2.

Comment: More on `Deployment target `, refer to the answer below:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15898159/667586

Answer (score 34):

You generally want to build against the latest SDK, but set the deployment target to the earliest you can. So, to run on as many devices as possible, use SDK 4.1, but set your deployment target to 3.0 or 3.1.3. I strongly suggest getting hold of an older iPod touch and testing on older devices if you want to support them. Its easy to miss an API call that's only supported on, say, 4.0.

Comment: It is a shame that apple does not allow downgrading devices for testing purposes. I already filed a feature request in their bug reporter but I do not think it will change soon.

Comment: Agreed, but it's not quite as bad as Ben's answer implies... XCode and Interface Builder will both generate warnings if you explicitly use APIs or constructs that aren't supported by your deployment version.  But it's still possible to get yourself into trouble here since it's difficult to test.

Comment: Thanks! There is an option "Compiler Default" which says that the code will load on any device which supports the API calls. What do you think about that? Can I set that up!

Comment: @GorillaPatch, Apple does allow downgrading iPod Touch devices.  So they are the more useful test devices for regression testing.

Comment: @hotpaw2 I have to test this, as I am using an iPod touch for testing anyways. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Downgrading info: http://www.ehow.com/how_12042911_downgrade-ipod-touch-421-402.html