# how to add older SDK's to xcode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

Good Evening,
The problem is that i have both xcode 3.2 and xcode 4 and i want to transfer the installed sdks from xcode 3.2 to xcode 4.0. is that even possible?? I am building an app for 3.1.3 in xcode 3.2 and i want to transfer my work to xcode 4.0. Is it as simple as copying the sdks from one folder to another?

I hope my question is clear.

thank you,

L_Sonic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just set the iOS deployment target to 3.1 in your project settings. I don't know if XCode will actually warn you if you're using an API call that's only available in 4.0 though.

More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703612/iphone-app-basesdk-and-ios-deployment-target).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test on older devices, you may install simulators at xCode preferences/Downloads/Components.