# Run iOS 5 application in iPhone 4.3.3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I am creating an `iPhone` project for iOS 5. I need to know if i can run the program in `iPhone` `4.3.3` and higher ?

Answer (score 4):

Are you using anything in your code that was introduced with iOS 5.0 & newer?  (such as storyboards)

If your answer is yes, then you can't run it on 4.3.3.

If no, then you can set the minimum required version to 4.3.X ([and here's a tutorial you can use](http://www.buildingiphoneapps.com/2011/01/minimum-required-ios-version.html)).

[Here is a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688333/how-to-use-xcode-compiler-warnings-to-determine-minimum-ios-deployment-target) ([and another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703612/iphone-app-basesdk-and-ios-deployment-target)) that may help you out a bit more.

Comment: I haven't used storyboard, i coded everything from scratch even a label was positioned by code

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, you can configure the simulator in xCode to emulate an earlier version of iOS so you can confirm whether or not it will work on 4.3.3.  Have a look at the build settings for your project, you can change the target O/S.  I'm not sure all versions are available by default though.  You might need to download other versions to test.

Comment: from where can i download other versions to test ?

Comment: I'm on xCode 4.0.2 and it's letting me set my deployment target to every version of iOS from 3.0 upwards (I just checked), so it looks like you should have it included.  You can also install an earlier version of xCode alongside if needs be.

Comment: You can't install Xcode 3 onto a 10.7 machine (it can be previously installed on a 10.6 machine before upgrading to 10.7, but clean installs of Xcode 3 will refuse to install on Lion); but Xcode 4's Simulator's "OS Version" can be changed to simulate iOS 3.2 or 3.3-something... so that's a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

You said you are using ARC. ARC will work with iOS 4.x, but not iOS 3.x.  So ARC will not be a problem.  Based on everything else you said about not using storyboards and everything being coded, you should be okay.  If you click on a method in Xcode it should allow you to bring up the documentation, and in the documentation it will provide the iOS version that it was released for.  Make sure that this it iOS 4.3.3 or lower.

Comment: Thank you, i was scared that i might have to redo the project. Like @DevinGund and Michael said i should test it by changing the targets.