# Deployment Targets

Tags: iphone, ios

IF I set the deployment target for my app to iOS 6 and when submitting to app store, will users with iOS 4.3 (or ios5) be not able to download install the app itself?how can i deploy app that work on ios4.3 to ios6 .please help.

Comment: set the deployment target as 4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with your code and set deployment **Target as 4.3** in project Setting...

Comment: is there any setting in base sdk?now its latest iOS6.0

Comment: No need to change base sdk. Because your base sdk need to be in ios6.0. You have to change deployment target only. That means you will make build using ios6.0 sdk which compatible from 4.3..

Answer (score 0):

> **IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET**
>
> **Description** :
>
> Code will load on this and
>   later versions of iOS.  Framework APIs that are unavailable in earlier
>   versions will be weak-linked; your code should check for null function
>   pointers or specific system versions before calling newer APIs.
>   [IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET]
>
> iOS 4.3 - Code will not load on systems earlier than 4.3. [4.3]
>
> iOS 5.0 - Code will not load on systems earlier than 5.0. [5.0]
>
> iOS 5.1 - Code will not load on systems earlier than 5.1. [5.1]
>
> iOS 6.0 - Code will not load on systems earlier than 6.0. [6.0]

To Deploy apps on ios 4.3 set the `iOS Deployment target` to 4.3

Answer (score 0):

The clear answer is NO
You have to set Your Deploy Target to 4.3

[image]